# React Typescript - Show hidden Divs not currently showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, toggle

I have an array that contains `Title1`, `Title2`, `Title3`, all the way to `Title8`. If that item is not empty I want to display with it's corresponding information. Currently that works.

However I want to add a button that will allow me to display all fields. For example let's say `Title1` through `Title3` is not null. It will show that (which it currently does). I want to add a button that when clicked will display all `Titles` 1-8.

Here is my current code. In the code below I'm only showing 4 if statements and removed all content to save space:

```
{ this.state.showExtraRows? <div>    
    { this.state.Product[0].Title1 ? 
        <div>
            //Display some fields here
        </div>

        : null
    }    

    { this.state.Product[0].Title2 ? 
        <div>
            //Display some fields here
        </div>

        : null
    }    

    { this.state.Product[0].Title3 ? 
        <div>
            //Display some fields here
        </div>

        : null
    }    

    { this.state.Product[0].Title4 ? 
        <div>
            //Display some fields here
        </div>

        : null
    } 
</div>
: null 
} 


<button className={styles.btn}
    type="button"   
    onClick={()=>{this.setState({showExtraRows:!this.state.showExtraRows})}}>
    { this.state.showExtraRows? 'Hide Rows' : 'Show Rows'}
</button>
```

I'm not too sure if I'm supposed to wrap the whole thing in the `this.state.showExtraRows?` statement.

Comment: Not totally related to your question but it will help you. Break your component into smaller component and pass the values needed as props. So on the parent run a forEach on the array and send it props in to the new component. There you can have they show based on the showExtraRows and also on their content. It will isolate the logic and make it better to visualize/debug.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use a map function here

```
const productWithTitles = this.state.Product.filter((Product) => !!Product.title);
return (
  <div>
    {this.state.showExtraRows && (
      <div>
        {productWithTitles.slice(0, 3).map((product) => {
          return (
            <div>
              //Display some fields here
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    )}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Is there a way to maybe add a class around that parent div. And on button click it toggles to show all those fields instead?